# Push down an <img> by 50% of its height and still affect flow

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Let's say I have this sample code

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel/100/200" />
    <p>
        Bla bla bla bla
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to push the img by 50% of its own height and also push the `<p>` down.
But how?

- Margin and Padding percentages refer to the `width` of the parent
- Top can only be used with positions that don't push other elements
- Translate doesn't affect layout

---

My idea was to find a way to store the ratios of the images in an attribute and push the image by 50% divided by the ratio (so it uses the height) but I don't see any way to use the attribute in the CSS (as the `attr()` can't be used outside a `content`).
And I would like to avoid having to add javascript resize events.

Also, it's on a responsive website so I can't hardcode the margin values.

---

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Push down, like when you use a margin-top.

No event, it should be always like that, that's why I don't want to use a resize event.

Comment: You say, "store the ratios of the images in an attribute", does that mean you already know what the image sizes are? If so, you can use an attribute. The style attribute that is. `style="margin-top:100px"` for a 200px high image.

Comment: Yes, I can store the image ratio but applying a margin top would only work in the initial case.

I forgot to mention it's a responsive site, the images will often change sizes.

Comment: Oh, 50% of the height it's currently displayed at? Yes, that's impossible with CSS. Use a resize event to trigger some JavaScript, as isherwood says.

Comment: Huh, guess I'll have to use the dreaded resize after all, thanks :)

Comment: Or if you want to do it the easy way, just edit the images themselves and put some white space in. Then they will always work without needing JavaScript or CSS!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find other solution here is JQuery https://jsfiddle.net/d4ggj5q9/
HTML

```
<div class="somediv">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <p>
      Bla bla bla bla
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var imageHeight = $('.image').height() / 2;
$('.somediv').css('margin-top', imageHeight);
```

**EDIT**

Updating on resize

```
$(window).resize(margin);
$(document).ready(margin);

function margin() {
    var imageHeight = $('.image').height() / 2;
    $('.somediv').css('margin-top', imageHeight);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would only work on the initial load. After resizing, the images will change size.

Comment: Then run it again on `window.resize`. There's no way to do it with CSS, and you need some event to trigger the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var ht = $(this).height();
    ht = ht / 2 + 'px';

    $(this).css('margin-top', ht);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g00hbd80/)**